# Designing a secure protocol to avoid MITM?

Tags: protocol-design

> Imagine that you are designing an online game, the framework consists of a player A, a game host H and a trusted central server S.
>
> The player A has a symmetric key KAS and id A that is known to the trusted central server (these would be set up using a registration key printed on the CD box).
>
> The host and server have well known public keys.
>
> The player will connect to the host H and set up a symmetric session key with which to play the game. You want to ensure that only people who have bought the game can play online. Therefore the host H will have to check with the server S that the player A really does have a key.
>
> Design a protocol that will let A connect to the host H and let H check with the server S to see if A is a legitimate player (i.e., really does have a shared key with S).
>
> There is only one server but there may be a number of hosts and players. In particular, your protocol should make it impossible for an attacker to wrongly authenticate with a host by intercepting and replaying messages or by acting as a man-in-the-middle.

What I have tried:
\begin{align}
A \rightarrow H&: E_{K_{AS}}[A, n_1], A\\
H \rightarrow S&: E_{S_{pub}}[E_{K_{AS}}[A, n_1], K_{AH}, n_2]\\
S \rightarrow H&: E_{H_{pub}}[\{A, n_2, K_{AH}\}, E_{K_{AS}}[K_{AH}, n_1]]\\
H \rightarrow A&: E_{K_{AS}}[K_{AH}, n_1]\\
A \leftrightarrow H&: E_{K_{AH}}[game play]
\end{align}

Am I somewhat on the right path here, or did I miss anything important?

Comment: What are $n_1$ and $n_2$?

Comment: @puzzlepalace *nounces*, random numbers that are sent in order to prevent replay attack. A nounce should never be allowed to be used twice for this reason.